In-App massaging - push notidfication
Our customer have a in-App massaging enabled in salesforce. Now for our customer have a mobile app where they have their customer user to chat with salesforce agent. Now their ask is when customer close their mobile app where they use to chat with the agent, but after some time agent try to connect with customer and send a message. Now the customer ask is that when agent send a message to customer when he/she is not online notify the mobile application. If we use push notification the mobile team dont want get notification each time agent message to customer, they only need push notification when customer is offline or inactive. Do anyone have any idea how can we archive it.
